# How to make the strtok working when reading the pathnames?

Tags: c

In this code, I am trying to `split` the pathnames with the help of `strtok()`. I am watching the `\n` sign to differentiate different pathnames. Although when I print the `path` variable, it gives all the pathnames.

But when I split them and print the `token[1]` variable, it gives me the `segmentation fault.` I used `token[0]`, but it gave me all the pathnames as it was printed with the `path` variable but without `\n` sign concatenated with pathnames.

```
int watch(char *dirname) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entity;
    char path[500] = { 0 };
    char *token[2];

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (dir != NULL) {
        while (entity = readdir(dir)) {
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s", dirname, entity->d_name);
            strcat(path, "\n");
            token[0] = strtok(path, "\n");
            token[1] = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            printf("%s\n", token[1]);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    } else {
        perror("Couldn't open the directory");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it returned Null

Comment: According to what i see from echo'ing PATH on windows and linux, the path separator is either colon or semicolon. Is there a reason to use \n as path separator other than "it was the first one coming to my mind"?

Comment: NOTE: [in unix] `\n` is a valid character in a filename. Only `\0` and `/` are forbidden. [plus a strong advice **not** to use `strtok()` ever]

Comment: BTW: what is the *purpose* of this program ?

Comment: @wildplasser which thing to use if I want to divide a string with the difference of newline?

Comment: A hand-coded loop, maybe using strchr() or strspn()/strcspn() [BUT: in your case, there is no `\n` in your string, except for the one you added yourself! ]

Answer (score 1):

The given code does not make sense and it is unclear what the real purpose is.

As it stands `token[1]` will always be `NULL`. As the string to tokenize is something like `"dirfilename\n"` and then split on `\n`. The second call to `strtok` always returns `NULL`.

So the question remains, what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: The reason for  `NULL` is that the `path` variable contains different paths. I used `token[0] = token(path, "\n")` to take the first path and `token[1] = token(NULL, "\n")` to take the second path and so on.

Comment: @Skywifibrand  but `path` only contains one filename! Every time `readdir` returns the next entry `path` is overwritten with a new filename. (which is missing the / though)

Comment: `I used this code
strcat(path, dirname);
strcat(path, entity->d_name);
strcat(path, "\n");
instead of this code, 
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s", dirname, entity->d_name);
and it worked`

Comment: @Skywifibrand, now you do something completely different and those `strtok` calls within the loop make even less sense.

Comment: Although I used `strtok` but instead of `snprintf` I used `strcat` as I wrote in above comment.

Comment: @Skywifibrand, I did understand that. But still the purpose of the code is still a mistery.

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating the dirname and filename, you do not insert a `/` between them. Use `"%s/%s"` to make it a pathname.

It is unclear why there should be any `;` in the pathname. This might be a confusion with the `PATH` variable.

Here is a simple program to enumerate files from the directories in the `PATH` variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int list_path(const char *p, int len) {
    char path[1024];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entity;
    int count = 0;

    if (len + 2 > (int)sizeof(path))
        return -1;

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%.*s", len, p);
    dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir != NULL) {
        while ((entity = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(entity->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entity->d_name, ".."))
                continue;
            count++;
            snprintf(path + len, sizeof(path) - len, "/%s", entity->d_name);
            printf("%s\n", path);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    const char *pathsep = ":";   // use `;` for Windows
    int len;

    if (path) {
        while (*path) {
            len = strcspn(path, pathsep);
            list_path(path, len);
            path += len + (path[len] != '\0');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just added `;` sign to differentiate different pathnames. Although I could use `"\n"`